# Удалить часть массива по значение

Tags: php, массивы

имеется переменная в которой содержаться массив содержащий более 15к значений. Нужно удалить из массива элементы содержащие в себе значение такого вида:

```
[121] => /contacts/_/
[923] => /contacts/_/_10/
[2408] => /contacts/_/_97-a/
```

они и дальше так растут, но всегда начинаются на /contacts/_/

как это сделать максимально быстро и эффективно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15к всё равно придётся проверять как ни крути, поэтому предлагаю сделать это встроенными средствами php.

```
$arr = [
    121 => '/contacts/_/',
    923 => '/contacts/_/_10/',
    2408 => '/contacts/_/_97-a/'
];

$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($var) {
    return strpos($var, '/contacts/_/') === false;
});

var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: похоже на правду, только какая функция должна быть то?)function ($var) {
  if (strpos($var, '/contacts/_/') !== false) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

Comment: @Fox056 не понял вопроса) просто подставьте свой массив за место моего `$arr` и Вам выведется массив без значений которые начинаются на `/contacts/_/`

Comment: @Fox056 то что Вы написали в качестве примера функции не нужно. `if` в данном случае избыточен, чтобы вывести  `boolean` значение не обязательно писать `if`

Comment: ваше решение почти сработало, только пришлось подправить, потому что возвращается 0, а не false

Comment: $newArr = array_filter($arItem, function($var) {
        return stristr($var, '/contacts/_/') === false;
    }); вот так работает

Comment: @Fox056 strpos когда возвращает 0 это значит что он нашел совпадение в самом начале строки (например 121 => '/contacts/_/', вернет 0) Поэтому в функции я сравниваю полученное значение  так `===`. И говорю фильтру удалить его или нет. Ну если у Вас всё работает как надо после правок, то рад помочь)